# regarding text.common_contexts() of nltk

Tags: nltk

what is the prime purpose of the using  text.common_contexts() in nltk.Guys I have searched and gone through as best as I could do. but sorry to say I didn't understand a bit.please help me by giving an example.Thank you.

Comment: I think you should support your question with a specific example/code. Literally, you are asking for educational content, which is not the purpose of this forum.

Comment: See http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html section 1.3

Comment: Very nicely explained in the link below: [common_contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438008/difference-between-similar-and-concordance-in-nltk)

Answer (score 3):

> **Example to understand:**

Let's first define our input text, I will just Copy/Paste the first paragraph of [Game of Thrones Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Thrones):

```
input_text = "Game of Thrones is an American fantasy drama television series \
created by David Benioff and D. B. Weiss for HBO. It is an adaptation of A Song \
of Ice and Fire, George R. R. Martin's series of fantasy novels, the first of \
which is A Game of Thrones. The show was filmed in Belfast and elsewhere in the \
United Kingdom, Canada, Croatia, Iceland, Malta, Morocco, Spain, and the \
United States.[1] The series premiered on HBO in the United States on April \
17, 2011, and concluded on May 19, 2019, with 73 episodes broadcast over \
eight seasons. Set on the fictional continents of Westeros and Essos, Game of \
Thrones has several plots and a large ensemble cast, and follows several story \
arcs. One arc is about the Iron Throne of the Seven Kingdoms, and follows a web \
of alliances and conflicts among the noble dynasties either vying to claim the \
throne or fighting for independence from it. Another focuses on the last \
descendant of the realm's deposed ruling dynasty, who has been exiled and is \
plotting a return to the throne, while another story arc follows the Night's \
Watch, a brotherhood defending the realm against the fierce peoples and \
legendary creatures of the North."
```

To be able to apply nltk functions we need to convert our text of type 'str' to 'nltk.text.Text'.

```
import nltk

text = nltk.Text( input_text.split() )
```

> **text.similar()**

The similar() method takes an input_word and returns other words who appear in a similar range of contexts in the text.

For example let's see what are the words used in similar context to the word 'game' in our text:

```
text.similar('game') #output: song web
```

> **text.common_contexts()**

The common_contexts() method allows you to examine the contexts that are shared by two or more words. Let's see in which context the words 'game' and 'web' were used in the text:

```
text.common_contexts(['game', 'web']) #outputs a_of
```

This means that in the text we'll find 'a game of' and 'a song of'.

> **These methods are especially interesting when your text is quite large (book, magazine...)**

Answer (score 1):

Observe the below example. You will understand:

```
>>> text1.concordance("tiger")
```

> of miles you wade knee - deep among Tiger - lilies -- what is the
> one charm wa
>  but nurse the cruellest fangs : **the** tiger **of**
> Bengal crouches in spiced groves
>   e would be more hideous than a
> caged tiger , then . I could not endure the sigh

```
>>> text1.concordance("bird")
```

> o the winds when that storm - tossed bird is on the wing . The three
> correspon
>     , Ahab seemed not to mark this wild bird ; nor ,
> indeed , would any one else
>    nd incommoding Tashtego there ; this
> bird now chanced to intercept its broad f
>  his hammer frozen there
> ; and so **the** bird **of** heaven , with archangelic shrieks

```
text1.common_contexts(["tiger","bird"])
```

> **the**_**of**