# Similar function in NLTK always return 'No Matches' result

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to use the similar function in NLTK with python but it keeps returning 'No Matches', even when I put in a similar word that's in the sentence.

My code is here

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import nltk
raw = "Analyzing text to find common terms using Python and NLTK"
text = nltk.Text(raw)
text.similar('mutual')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`Text` takes a list of words, not a string:

```
text = nltk.Text(word_tokenize(raw))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to use your code. But still similar function return 'No Matches' result. Any other ideas?

Comment: Sometimes there are indeed no matches. Like in your original example, because the word 'mutual' is not even in the text.

Comment: Similar function return the similar word of a given word, not exact word of a given word. Is that correct or not? 
In my example the word 'common' is in the text. Its a similar word of 'mutual'. So my example need to return the word 'common'. But always return 'No Matches'.

Comment: Your interpretation of the function `similar()` is incorrect. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438008/difference-between-similar-and-concordance-in-nltk

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now i am clear in similar() function.